# Select oldest HABTM record with group by clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to show a line chart on the admin page (with [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick)) with the incremental number of scores related to their earliest export date.

I have the following models:

```
# score.rb

class Score < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :export_orders, join_table: :scores_export_orders
end

# export_order.rb

class ExportOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :scores, join_table: :scores_export_orders
end
```

How do I select, for each `Score` having at least one `ExportOrder`, the corresponding `ExportOrder` with the earliest `created_at` (in date only format)?

I had a look at [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ordering-within-a-sql-group-by-clause), but my situation has a HABTM relationship instead of a simple has_many.

I tried this code, to get at least a mapping between oldest export date and number of scores:

```
sql = "
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT scores.id), MIN(export_orders.created_at::date)
FROM
  scores
INNER JOIN
  scores_export_orders
ON
  scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id
INNER JOIN
  export_orders
ON
  export_orders.id = scores_export_orders.export_order_id
GROUP BY
  export_orders.created_at::date
".split("\n").join(' ')
query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
query.map { |v| [v['count'], v['min']] }
```

but the total number of scores is greater than all scores having an export date.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has better performance than [Mark's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792549/5903989) since it relies on pure SQL. Basically, the GROUP BY clause required grouping by `scores_export_orders.score_id` rather than `export_orders.created_at`:

```
sql = "
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT scores_export_orders.score_id), MIN(export_orders.created_at::date)
INNER JOIN
  scores_export_orders
INNER JOIN
  export_orders
ON
  export_orders.id = scores_export_orders.export_order_id
GROUP BY
  scores_export_orders.score_id
".split("\n").join(' ')
query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
query.map { |v| [v['count'], v['min']] }
```

I couldn't find an exact equivalent in ActiveRecord instructions (all of such attempts were giving me strange results), so executing the SQL will also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :export_orders, join_table: :scores_export_orders

  def earliest_export_date
    export_orders.pluck(&:created_at).min
  end
end
```

This will let you call `@score.earliest_export_date`, which should return the value you want.

I also think it's the most performant way to do it in ruby, although someone may correct me on that.

Comment: To collect all the dates, I can run `map` on all scores and then use your method. This can lead to a ~10s latency with ~1500 score entries. Is there a better way for this?